# How to Capture .mp4 using Osprey PCI-X 440 card

Tags: visual-c++, video, streaming, capture

I am using Osprey PCI-X 440 card purchased from http://www.viewcast.com.
Now i want to capture .mp4 file from live streaming using this device.
can anyone please help me how can i achieve it?

Thanks in advance,
Dhaval

Answer (score 2):

Once you have installed the correct drivers for your osprey card from the viewcast site, you can use VLC for this as following:

1. Open VLC, Click on Media->Convert/Save...
2. Open Capture Device Tab, select the video device as your osprey video device and audio device as the osprey audio device. Click on Covert/Save.
3. Now select the video profile as MP4 (or whatever else you may require). In the destination File, click browse and choose your file location. Check the display output box.
4. Click Start & press stop when you have finished recording.